# Formrequest and Scrapy. Fill out a form

Tags: forms, scrapy, submit

I would like to fill out a form using formrequest and scrapy. However, I'am stuck and I don't know how to continue to submit the form . I would be very grateful if someone could help me. This is the code I'm using:

```
import scrapy
def authentication_failed(response):
# TODO: Check the contents of the response and return True if 
it failed
# or False if it succeeded.
    pass

class IdealistaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "MiPrimerSpider" 
    custom_settings = {'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36'
    }
    start_urls = https://www.idealista.com/inmueble/94342193/']

    def parse(self, response):
       return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response,formxpath="//div[@class='modulecontact_form']/form[@class='formcontact']",
       formdata={'contact-email': 'an email','contact-phone':'a number phone','contact-name':'costaman','privacy-policy-checkbox':' ','recommendations-checkbox':None},
        clickdata={'class': 'btn action txt-bold txt-big desktop'},
        callback=self.after_login
    )
    def after_login(self, response):
        if authentication_failed(response):
           self.logger.error("Login failed")
           return
```

Comment: 'https://www.idealista.com/inmueble/94342193/' is not the login page... you're trying to fill a form that doesn't exists...

Comment: It's a contact foorm. It seems that when you click on the message boss then the rest of the boxes appear including a privacy policy checkbox. Doesn't Formrequest work with any form? If not, How could I fill out this form by using Scrapy? thanks